# Errors showing for OES OpenGL statements in Xcode 6 for iOS8

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, ios8, xcode6

Xcode 6 iOS SDK 8.0 in Yosemite is giving me errors for OpenGL ES2 code which compiles fine under Xcode 5

```
GLuint depthStencilRenderbuffer;
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthStencilRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES,
                         GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES,
                         self.view.bounds.size.width,
                         self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

Generates errors:

line 2:

Conflicting types for 'glBindRenderBufferOES'

Use of undeclared identifier 'GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES'

line 3:

implicit declaration of contain 'glBindRenderBufferOES' is invalid in C99

Edit: OK, I can get things working again by substituting:

```
GLuint depthStencilRenderbuffer;
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthStencilRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                      GL_STENCIL_INDEX8,
                      self.view.bounds.size.width,
                      self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

Still - I don't know why this change is needed and I'd appreciate some further insight as to what's going on here.

Comment: `glRenderbufferStorageOES()` and `GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES` are in the `GL1/glext.h` header in SDK 7.1. My guess is that something indirectly include that header in SDK 7.1, and is not anymore in SDK 8.0. There's no need to use the ES 1.1 extensions for those anyway, since they are standard in ES 2.0. `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES` is a different case, since it's not standard in ES 2.0. Include `<OpenGLES/GL2/glext.h>` in your code to get that defined.

Answer (score 54):

Try:

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

or

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES3/glext.h>
```

works for me.

Without it, app which correctlyworking on xcode 6 + ios7 can find GL_FALSE and others..

Comment: I had the problem with GL_RED_EXT, but works for me. tnx

Comment: @Niedved.. Super boss. I am working on a prestegious project and I were not knowing to import these two files.Thank you sooo much.

Comment: Fixed GL_RED_EXT with XCode 6 for me too (was working without it on XCode 5)

Comment: in case any googler searched for `GL_FALSE`, this solution works for this too.

Answer (score 6):

I think @reto-koradi's comment is correct.  I had a problem in my code that was similarly broken in iOS8.  They've changed how some of the headers include other headers so here are the steps I took:

1. Got to Xcode5 and locate the same line that is broken in Xcode6/iOS8.
2. Command-click that link and find out which header file it's in.
3. Go back to Xcode6/iOS8 and find that file.

For me it was `#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>` because some of the glextensions I was using was missing.