# Implicit declaration of function 'glReadPixels' is invalid in C99 compiling on ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a Problem when I try to compiling my iOS project with iOS 8.

The errors messages are:

```
 Implicit declaration of function 'glReadPixels' is invalid in C99 compiling
 Conflicting types for 'glReadPixels'
 Declaration of 'glReadPixels' must be imported from module 'OpenGLES.ES3.gl' before it is required
```

Comment: Sounds like an include ordering problem.  Are you referencing glReadPixels anywhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors showing for OES OpenGL statements in Xcode 6 for iOS8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024764/errors-showing-for-oes-opengl-statements-in-xcode-6-for-ios8)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recently I have faced the same issue.

The easiest way to resolve this problem is by adding `@import OpenGLES;` line in each file where you have got this message.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 8 is necessary Import

```
  #import <OpenGLES/ES3/glext.h>
```

This link is the solution [Click Here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024764/errors-showing-for-oes-opengl-statements-in-xcode-6-for-ios8)